# Join on polymorphic association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi guys I know that this is really bad idea but I want join three tables for my query on polymorphic association

for example

```
class Article
  has_many :comments, :as=>:commentable
end

class Post
  has_many :comments, :as=>:commentable
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic=>:true
end
```

and I need to get something similar to

```
Comment.all(:joins=>:commentable)
```

of course I can't write exactly such join but I need something that can join this three tables

I'm writing cimplicate search by several tables User can choose different options Let's say that `User has_one Comment` and I want select all users who commented something (Article or Post) that includes some phrase So I need something similar to `User.all(:joins=>{:comments=>:commentable}, :conditions=>["articles.body LIKE (?) OR posts.header LIKE (?)", value, value])`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Comment` your third class? And what exactly do you want to do? Maybe we can suggest another way you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the thing I want to do is impossible because

join format

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

and I must join tables on commentable_id without any difference for different tables That would be a mess But maybe I am wrong

**Edits**
I did next

```
User.all(:joins=>"clean sql inner join of three tables on commentable_id", 
:conditions=>[" (comments.commentable_class="Article" AND articles.body LIKE (?)) 
             OR (comments.commentable_class="Post" AND posts.header LIKE (?))", value, value])
```

I'm still refactoring code and I'll post the result later